# Update pyqtgraph ImageView image without changing scale and translation

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I have an ImageView where I would like to update the image without initializing the display (zoom, translation, etc...) to the default centered, non-scaled view.

I have a process that update the image pixel values and I would like to be able to zoom in on some region of the image before applying these changes to see the local modifications happen .

However each call to setImage to update the image initializes the zoom and the position of the image within the view.

I have tried to save the QTransform before updating the image and use this transform as input to setImage. This had no effect on the resulting image.

```
class myImageView(pg.ImageView):
    def __init__(self):
       ......

    def setImage(self, img, autoRange=True, autoLevels=True,
                 levels=None, axes=None, xvals=None, pos=None,
                 scale=None, transform=None, autoHistogramRange=True):
        self.min_level, self.max_level = self.ui.histogram.getLevels()
        # get the current transform
        transform = self.imageItem.transform()
        # update the image displayed
        pg.ImageView.setImage(self, img, autoRange=autoRange, autoLevels=autoLevels,
                     levels=levels, axes=axes, xvals=xvals, pos=pos,
                     scale=scale, transform=transform, autoHistogramRange=autoHistogramRange)
        # update the histogram
        self.ui.histogram.setLevels(self.min_level, self.max_level)
        # try to apply the transform to the image item
        self.imageItem.setTransform(transform)
```

The resulting image is automatically centered and zoom re-initialized.

Is there a way to keep the previous zoom and translations used and apply them again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just set autoRange to False

```py
image_view = pg.ImageView()
image_view.setImage(img_original)

# this will disable rescaling and translate
image_view.setImage(img_new, autoRange=False)
```

Doc: https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/widgets/imageview.html#pyqtgraph.ImageView.setImage